# Date Validation?

Tags: validation

Below is the validation rule which I have written:

```
AND(
BRP_Unconditional__c = true,
NOT(OR(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) < DATE(2016, 20, 3),
Web_Form_Source__c = "goldrush.oliverhume.com.au",
NOT(ISBLANK(GSR_Referral_Date_Time__c)))
))
&&
(NOT($User.ProfileId = '00e90000000JW4E'))
```

The concern is DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) < DATE(2016, 20, 3).
It seems its not firing, if I remove this line of code it's working. The reason to write this piece to consider only Opportunities which are created after 20th March 2016. Please suggest.

Regards,
Ata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here that you use this date validation in `OR` operator when you want it to be a mandatory requirement

```
AND(
 BRP_Unconditional__c,
 DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) >= DATE(2016, 20, 3),
 Web_Form_Source__c <> "goldrush.oliverhume.com.au",
 NOT(ISBLANK(GSR_Referral_Date_Time__c))
)
&&
($User.ProfileId <> '00e90000000JW4E')
```

Also, it's not recommended to use any Ids in validations, or even Names that can be changed over time. Look for `Custom settings` and how they can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not working with a `DATE()` function but it should work like this:

```
DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) < DATEVALUE("2016-03-20")
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up month and day parameters of a DATE function,
the method signature is `DATE(year,month,day)`.

So it should be

```
AND
(
    BRP_Unconditional__c = true,
    NOT
    (
        OR
        (
            DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) < DATE(2016, 3, 20),
            Web_Form_Source__c = "goldrush.oliverhume.com.au",
            NOT(ISBLANK(GSR_Referral_Date_Time__c))
        )
    )
)
&&
(NOT($User.ProfileId = '00e90000000JW4E'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide date parameter ins Y/M/D format.
I think you have swapped day with month and month with day.

Reference:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&language=en_US